How to fix error -- CS1061 in wpf when finding 1st argument that does not exist?"?
I have a problem in WPF that when I try to give a button some event (here, click), it pops the error message

'MainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'ToggleB1_Click' and no
accessible extension method 'ToggleB1_Click' accepting a first
argument of type 'MainWindow' could be found (are you missing a using
directive or an assembly reference?)

The error happens in the mainwindow.xaqml file in line 13 where the button tag is used. I have tried to attach the event handler twice to see if it works but it just gives the same error.
The MainWindow.xaml code is this:
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Name="Hello" FontSize="70" FontWeight="DemiBold"
        VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />

    <Button Click="ToggleB1_Click" Name="ToggleB1" Content="Click" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
        Width="200" 
        Height="50" FontSize="30" Background="Black"
        Foreground="White" />
    </Grid>
</Window>


The MainWindow.xaml.cs code is this:
namespace C__experiments_WPF_
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        bool running = false;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ToggleB1.Click += ToggleB1_Click;
        }

        private void ToggleB1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            running = !running;
            if (running)
            {
                 ToggleB1.Content = "Stop";
                 Hello.Text = "Hello";
            }
            else
            {
                ToggleB1.Content = "Start";
                Hello.Text = "Bye";
            }
        }
    }
}

I am using .NET 8 and wpf
I have tried to change the names, change the .net version and everything else on the internet (I'm not exaggerating). Also, cleaning and rebuilding the project or deleting the obj and bin folders and rebuilding it doesn't work.

Except that attaching the Click handler twice breaks the intended behavior, your code compiles and runs successfully. The error must be somewhere else. Perhaps try setting up a new project.

"mainwindow.xaqml file in line 13 where the button tag is used" - do you mean the line starting with <Button Click="ToggleB1_Click" ?

Yes, the <Button Click="ToggleB1_Click" line
